# What am I doing wrong?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, gravity, potential

This seems a rather simple question and I feel silly for asking it, but I don't know what I am doing wrong.

> On Earth a person is able to jump 1.5m. The person is now transported onto an asteroid with a density of 2500kgm-3. What must the size of the asteroid be to ensure that the person is unable to jump off of its surface?

My first attempt at this entailed equating using an inequality on the energies/potential:

Maximum energy released in one jump: $ approx. 1.5gm$

where $m$ is the mass of the person.

Potential at the surface of the asteroid (and thus energy required to completely remove onseself from the gravitational potential field of the asteroid): $U=-\frac{GmM}{r}=\frac{Gm\rho _a r^3}{r}=Gm\rho _a r^2$

Now the inequality:

$1.5mg < Gm\rho r^2$

and I get the answer that the radius must be $9.4km$.

However the answer is $4.6km$ (although it does not say whether this refers to the radius or diameter)

I can't see what I could be doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your only mistake is to assume that the volume of a sphere is given by $V = r^3$.

This makes your answer wrong by a factor of $\sqrt{4\pi/3} \approx 2.05$, so that's why you're getting about twice the answer of the correct one.